# FileMaker 11: Can't widen layout?

Tags: filemaker

The company that I work for has been using FileMaker since v5, I believe. For some reason, in our database, we can't seem to widen any layouts beyond something like 615px - not even if I create a blank layout from scratch. However, if I create a new database, everything is as it should be. Here's a screenshot of what's going on, for clarification:

[image: Nothing that I do works.]

I don't get an option to drag it over or anything, but I can drag the layout up and down just as far as I please. Google's gotten me nowhere, and I've spent long enough hunting through settings and coming back empty-handed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the Page Margins option turned on. (View - Page Margins). Turn it off and your layouts will get back to normal.

Comment: Thank you so, so, so much... apparently, this has been causing headaches around the office for years. Thanks for saving the day!